# Entity Framework database-first with Oracle, Visual Studio 2015, can't create model class from existing database

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, ef-database-first

[Can't add model error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQGR4.png)

I got error when try to  create ADO.NET Entity Data Model from existing Oracle 11g database

[Server Explorer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3lnG.png).

My connection string worked on server explorer but when I try to create ADO.NET Entity Data Model. I downloaded ODAC 12c Release 4 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.1.0.2.4) (32 bit) and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess( 64bit) from nuget.

I am using Visual Studio 2015, Entity Framework 6, Oracle 11g, Windown 10 pro 64 bit

```
<configuration>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
                      type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />

<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
                 type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

I added some config to `web.config` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try opening project properties => Build => Platform target => set to x86, then rebuild project & add entity data model.

Comment: i set to x86, rebuild and try to add entity data model but still same error :(

Comment: What is your version of ODAC & ODT currently installed? ODAC 12c R3 supports EF6, which should be consider then. Also try setting provider to this: `<provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />`.

Comment: i downloaded ODAC 12c Release 4 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.1.0.2.4) (32 bit) . It is ODAC 12r4 because 12r3 doen't support visual studio 2015. i'll check settring privider now

Comment: the only thing different with provider is Version=4.121.2.0 and  Version=6.121.2.0,  and it doen't work :(

Comment: Ensure you have correct settings as given there: https://community.oracle.com/message/13114643#13114643. Certain sources mention usage of `4.121.2.0` in `configSections`, and `6.121.2.0` in `entityFramework` element of web.config & set `defaultConnectionFactory` with `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleConnectionFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework`.

Comment: Do i need to install Oracle Database 11g Release 2 or not?. Currently try to install vs 2013 because alot of helpfull page using vs 2013 not 2015

Comment: It depends by how the error can be resolved by upgrading DB version & your current needs. Commonly the error occurs when installed ODP/ODAC version doesn't support current EF version used, update both of them to any package which supports EF 6 & VS 2015.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto . My project worked on my pc but when i try to publish to windown server 2008. It doen't work :( . get this error Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection is invalid. I gonna make another questions too. but seem like manually config Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client bring alot of trouble

Comment: I want to find out if you're stumbled with troublesome error `Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection`. Seems that after-publishing scenario is different thing which requires another question to hold it.

Comment: yes, now i need another question for after-publishing scenario with manually config ODP by defaultConnectionFactory and self add Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.DLL reference . After publishing it keep telling me Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection is invalid . Anyway thanks for your support :D

Comment: Finally my project worked after-publishing  too. I install the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v12.2.110 from nuget( version 64bit which only support runtim) and remove some line from web.config which cause IIS  buged .And change my connection string from ezconnect to TNS Now it work for both dev/ product eviroment :D.

Answer (score 1):

Found The way to get it work, first you need to install entityframework 6 from nuget and then change the web.config file :

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleConnectionFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework">
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
```

But you need to add Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.DLL , get it from
ODAC 12c Release 4 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.1.0.2.4)  [odac 12 RC4 FOR VISUAL 2015, EF 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html)  my location for that file is D:\app\client\Unknow\product\12.1.0\client_1\odp.net\managed\common\EF6 where D is harddisk and Unknow is your pc name.
In the end it is install ODAC 12c r4,EF6, change  config file like the code and add Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.DLL to reference 
so you can use DB first with Oracle db like a boss :D